# Advanced Indexing: Vectorized way of assigning a (32,125) array into a (13,13,32,125) array by indexing the latter with two (32,) arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, vectorization

I am building the input pipeline for a neural network. I have a numpy arrays with following properties:

```
bboxes.shape => (32,125)
x_cell.shape => (32,)
y_cell.shape => (32,)
output.shape => (13,13,32,125)
```

What I want to do can be written as the following for loop, iterating through the batch (batch size = 32):

```
for i in range(32):
    output[x_cell[i], y_cell[i], i, :] = bboxes[i]

#eg shapes of indexing: output[(1,), (1,), (1,), :] = (125,)
```

However, I don't want to use a for loop, since that would be slow. How can further utilize numpy's features like multidimensional indexing, np.moveaxis()...etc to get this done elegantly?

Comment: The 32 larger than 13 bugs me.  That means there will be repeats.

Comment: 32 is the batch size, (13,13) is the cell grid across the image (TinyYOLO architecture). x_cell, y_cell are each (32,) shaped, denoting which cell contains the object for the entire batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
N = len(bboxes)
output[x_cell[:N],y_cell[:N],np.arange(N)] = bboxes
```

For the case with lengths of `x` and `y` cells being equal to length of `bboxes`, it would simplify to -

```
output[x_cell,y_cell,np.arange(N)] = bboxes
```

Comment: Sure! Thanks again!